# Insert variables inside quotes

Tags: sed

How insert variable inside quotes in this script?

```
f=`sed -n '1p' < /path/ls.txt`
```

I try something like this but it don't work..

```
f=`sed -n '"$i1"p' < /path/ls.txt`
```

Comment: No, i try adivce from this post and it not help me. I want incrase variable `$i` to take {1, 2, .. x} line from .txt file

Comment: You *didn't* try the solution from there, you tried something else. Compare your usage of quotes with that in the answer there.

Comment: `sed -n "$i"'p' < /raid/path/ls.txt` now it work, thanks!